# bootstrap default navbar dropdown not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created an [html file](https://gist.github.com/pcantalupo/330b64ffad9ae68f6e9c42818134264a) with the bootstrap default navbar example [from this page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). When I open the file in Chrome, Firefox, or IE, the dropdown menus do not work. However, the [bootstrap webpage showing the example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) does work in Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to include a reference to jQuery to make Bootstrap work.

Comment: i'm completely new to web development...how do I do that? ty

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach jquery and bootstrap js cdns as follows in your file.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</body>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include a reference to jQuery before you reference the Bootstrap javascript to make Bootstrap work. And you should also move the existing `script` element inside the `body` element, I guess:

```
    </nav>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmhjy89z/), even though the external resources are not visible within the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to web development in aition to the above answers I would like to add two more points--

**No.1**
Never add bootstrap dns twice in your page, it will create all sorts of trouble.

**No.2**

Add the cdn s in the following order--

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```